# escape dots in graphql query payload

Tags: graphql

I have a stackrox response like below

```
"metadata": {
        "v1": {
            "digest": "sha256:swdfwvfwveswdvedfvedfsverfv",
            "created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "author": "Jib",
            "layers": [
       
                {
                    "instruction": "RUN",
                    "value": "jib-gradle-plugin:3.3.0",
                    "created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "author": "Jib",
                    "empty": false
                }
            ],
            "user": "0",
            "command": [],
            "entrypoint": [
                "java",
                "-cp",
                "@/app/jib-classpath-file",
                "com.myorg.ecf.myapp.MyApp"
            ],
            "volumes": [],
            "labels": {
                "com.myorg.base.image": "artifactory.myorg.int/repo/distroless-java17.0.6:2023-02-13"
            }
        },
```

When I try to get labels I am getting below error

"message": "syntax error: unexpected "myorg", expecting "."",

Can somebody help me how to resolve this error.